# MS Access Simple Unmatched query not working with additional filter

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm sure this is a simple problem, but for some reason I'm not getting it and don't want to spend any more time trying to solve it.

I have a table with a list of vendors and another table which holds the activity for each vendor by Division.  I'm trying to write a query that will show me which vendor does not have any records of activity for a specific Division.

I have the following query that will show me what vendors do not have any records in the

```
SELECT VendorTbl.VendorID, VendorTbl.VendorName
FROM VendorTbl LEFT JOIN VendorActivities ON VendorTbl.[VendorID] = VendorActivities.[VendorID]
WHERE (((VendorActivities.VendorID) Is Null));
```

That works fine, however, if I try to further filter it by Division by adding `AND (VendorActivities.DivisionID)=3` to the `WHERE` clause, I get no results.  And in this case, I should get the same results because so far, all the records I have in my table are for Division 3.

Comment: the `AND (VendorActivities.DivisionID)=3` needs to be in the ON clause. However, this will work with any other databases, but Access. In Access you need to do it differently. lets wait what other people say

Comment: I just tried that and got a JOIN expression is not supported error.  Can you give me the specific code?

Comment: See below. I was hoping someone else will respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any other database engine this will work by simply including the AND (VendorActivities.DivisionID)=3 to the ON clause. This query will work in e.g. SQL Server:

```
SELECT VendorTbl.VendorID, VendorTbl.VendorName
FROM VendorTbl LEFT JOIN VendorActivities 
ON VendorTbl.[VendorID] = VendorActivities.[VendorID] AND VendorActivities.DivisionID=3
WHERE VendorActivities.VendorID Is Null;
```

However, this will work with any other databases, but Access. In Access you need to do it differently. One way to achieve this is to use a sub-query, like this:

```
SELECT VendorTbl.VendorID, VendorTbl.VendorName
FROM VendorTbl LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT VendorActivities.[VendorID] FROM VendorActivities WHERE VendorActivities.DivisionID=3) AS q
ON VendorTbl.[VendorID] = q.[VendorID]
WHERE q.VendorID Is Null;
```

Comment: I'm getting a missing operator in query expression error and the cursor goes to the position after "ON"

Comment: Sorry. Typo. I left the AND in the ON clause